# How to set default Language in ABP framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, localization, blazor, abp

I'm using Abp startup template with [Blazor UI and EF Core](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Setup-Environment?UI=Blazor&DB=EF&Tiered=No)
I'm building a single language web app and basically want to get rid of every other language and set Turkish ("tr")  for the default language/culture.

What is the **recommended way** to achieve this, without having to install any third-party NuGet package (such as [Owl](https://github.com/maliming/Owl.Abp.CultureMap))?

*Please note that I'm still new to the Abp Framework, so kindly include the file/project names in your answer(along with the code snippet, if possible)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove all other languages and use Turkish ("tr") by default, you can update the `ConfigureLocalization` method in the `ProjectNameHttpApiHostModule` file under the `ProjectName.HttpApi.Host` folder to include the only tr. For example, the content of the `ConfigureLocalization` method should now be as follows:

```cs
    private void ConfigureLocalization()
    {
        Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Languages.Add(new LanguageInfo("tr", "tr", "Türkçe"));
        });
    }
```

Then you should add the following to the `OnApplicationInitialization` method in the `ProjectNameHttpApiHostModule` file.

```cs
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("tr")
    };
    app.UseAbpRequestLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("tr");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
        {
            new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
            new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
        };
    });
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/2775) for more information.

Comment: In case someone else tries this and fails: *remove the cookies* to see the change.